# Default Alignment of structure members

Tags: c, x86-64

In X86_64 intel processor with gcc compiler, what is the default alignment of members in a 'C' structure. Is it self aligned to natural boundaries?

Comment: You may find what you are looking for by printing out the memory address of several members of the structure. `printf("Memory address of variable i is %d from the beginning of the struct",&(structure.variablei)-&structure);`

Comment: This is defined by the ABI you are using, which is usually determined by your OS.  On most (all?) Unix-like systems, you want to look at the [System V ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf).  The details are too long for an SO post.

Answer (score 0):

a struct is aligned to the same alignment as needed for the largest element type within the structure.

if the largest element is an int and on a 32bit architecture (or forcing compiling using 32bit instruction) will be on a 4byte boundary.

If compiling using 64bit instructions, will be on a 8byte boundary.

And similar for other types.